# How to overwrite resource file with less priority via Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin, maven-resources-plugin

in our maven module we have multiple resource folders

`src/main/prod/sql` and `src/main/dev/sql`. In prod we have scripts for production where are a lot of data inserts. We need overwrite some files in **prod/sql** directory with files in **dev/sql** when profile **local** is activated.

Here is configuration

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-files</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/sql</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>src/main/dev/</directory>
                                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

When we build modile with clean install there are always scripts from **prod/sql** in target directory. Can you tell me what I do wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you build with `mvn clean install`?

If thats the case, the `<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>` parameter is not allowing the `local` profile to be run by default, you should build with `mvn clean install -Plocal` which loads the `local` profile during build

Alternatively, modify `pom.xml` to always use the `local` profile:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
...
```